# WordPress: hide widgets from Post Window programmatically

Tags: wordpress, widget, dashboard

I'm burning my brain to find someway to hide some widgets from "Post Window" programmatically.

I found an article on WordPress.org that worked fine to hide some widgets from the Dashboard Window (ref.: http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Advanced:_Removing_Dashboard_Widgets). But unfortunately I didn't find any way to hide some widgets from Post Window.

I'd like to remove widgets like: Tags, Custom Fields and Post Thumbnail.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!
Taj Singh

Answer (score 0):

This plugin sounds like it does what you want: [WP-CMS Post Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-cms-post-control/):

> Post Control from WordPress CMS
>   Modifications gives you complete
>   control over your write options for
>   every user level/role. It not only
>   allows you to hides unwanted items
>   like custom fields, trackbacks,
>   revisions etc. but also gives you a
>   whole lot more control over how
>   WordPress deals with creating content.

I believe the relevant function called is [`remove_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action), though I have not dived deep into this area of WordPress yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use remove_meta_box(), see [read function docs **till the end**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box).